# Negative sign swapping in a python list

Tags: python, list, numbers, negative-number

```
x = [[-123 456],[567 -8910],[432 -890], [-567 976]]
```

I have a list of list, I want to swap the negative symbol of x and y elements of a list, if x is not negative it should be changed into negative and if y is negative it should be changed into positive (just have to change the symbol).

It should be like this:

```
x = [[-123 456],[-567 8910],[-432 890], [-567 976]]
```

I also want to extract all of the x elements in a separate list (for example: u = [-123,-567,-432,-567]) and y elements in a separate list (for example: v = [456, 8910, 980, 976]). Please suggest possible solutions.

The issue that I'm facing is that there are no commas between the elements

Comment: `- number` will flip the sign of a number.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: You can do it with nested list comprehensions.

Comment: BTW, you're missing commas in the inner lists.

Comment: There are no commas in between the elements

Comment: If there are no commas in between the inner elements, then it's a **Syntax Error**. You can't create a list of lists without having a comma between the elements of the inner list and between the elements of the outer list. Is it user-provided text input or something?

Comment: Is it a list of strings? Or a numpy array?

Comment: Where is the data coming from with no commas?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want all `x` to be negative and all `y` to be positive. `abs` can be very useful here. No need to check if negative or not.

```
data = [[-123, 456], [567, -8910], [432, -890], [-567, 976]]

output = [[-abs(x), abs(y)] for x, y in data]
```

And to get all of x and all of y in a list is another simple comprehension just exclude the value you don't want.

```
all_x = [x for x, y in data]
all_y = [y for x, y in data]
```

Comment: `abs()` always returns positive numbers. `-abs(x)` when `x` is `-123` will be `-123`. You're not flipping the sign.

Comment: @barmar Correct. They don't want it flipped in that situation.

Comment: I see, I didn't understand that the rule was different for x and y. Thought they just wanted to flip everything.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple if you are able to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[-123, 456],[567, -8910],[432, -890], [-567, 976]])
out = np.abs(x) * [-1, 1]

print(out)
```

Result:

```
> [[-123  456]
 [-567 8910]
 [-432  890]
 [-567  976]]
```

To split into separate arrays, simply use array slicing:

```
xArr = out[:,0]
yArr = out[:,1]
```

Comment: The output for last list is incorrect. It should be [-567, 976] according to OP.

Comment: I think it must be a typo in the OP's example as that doesn't seem to match his requirements

Comment: The main issue is that there are no commas in between the elements, that is why I'm getting error everytime,

Comment: Example is correct, we just need to shift the negative symbol from the second element to the first

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[-123, 456],[567, -8910],[432, -890], [-567, 976]])

# Negative-Number
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
  if(data[i][0]>0):
    data[i][0] = data[i][0]*-1
  if(data[i][1]<0):
    data[i][1] = data[i][1]*-1

# Store results
all_x = [x for x, y in data]
all_y = [y for x, y in data]
```

Output:

```
print("Output:\n",data)
print("all_x:\n",all_x)
print("all_y:\n",all_y)

Output:
 [[-123  456]
 [-567 8910]
 [-432  890]
 [-567  976]]
all_x:
 [-123, -567, -432, -567]
all_y:
 [456, 8910, 890, 976]
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy if you're not using numpy

Comment: Just a bad habit I guess